# Remove map-control panel from kepler.gl .html export

Tags: html, kepler.gl

Is there any way to remove the map-control panel (3D view, show legend, draw on map and select language) from the html export of a kepler.gl map?

All the answers i found concerned the `reducers` block which only removes the left side panel.

But i want to get rid of the options on the right.

Thanks in advance!